# dynamically build Intersect statement ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I would like to use the IEnumerable function Intersect() to combine a few list and get the similar integers from each list. The problem I'm faced with is that I don't know how many list I will need to compare.

Here is an example:

A{1,2,3,4}
B{1,2,3}
C{1,2}

results = A.Intersect(B).Intersect(C)

This works great, but the next time around I may have a D{1,2} next time I come across the function.

I'd like to use the Intersect method, but I'm open to new ideas as well.

Comment: How are you expecting to receive this lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are receivng the collections in a list, you could do this:

```
List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>();

  var result = lists[0].AsEnumerable();
  for (int i = 0; i < lists.Count - 1; i++)
  {
    result = result.Intersect(lists[i + 1]);
  }
```